# Reassign a object property

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

when I have a propery like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSUrlConnection *connection;
```

When I first assign a variable to the property it will be retained, but when I reassign the property to a new NSUrlConnection have I to release the property first and reassign after that?

```
[self.connection release];
self.connection = [........
```

I don't use ARC.

Comment: So you're using ARC?  You should mention that if so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties take care of memory management for you. There's no need to release it before you reassign it a new value. If you were using an ivar, that'd be different.

With a property, you can simply set it to `nil` to release it. When the property's retainCount reaches 0, it's automatically removed from memory.

Comment: That last sentence doesn't make sense;  a property retains/releases objects automatically.  Whether the object is deallocated when an it is released has nothing to do with the property.

Comment: What it means is that you don't need to call `release` on it to drop the `retainCount`. You can just set it to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's all handled for you. See http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/ in properties section.

Comment: Can you point me to the part? I dont see the related sentence.